# How to put label to left of input when the HTML is fixed -- I can only change the CSS

Tags: css, jquery-ui, datatables

Using DataTables, I have no control over the generated HTML. It automatically generates:

```
<div class="dataTables filter" id="categories_filter">
  <label>
    Search:
    <input type="text" aria-controls="categories">
  </label>
</div>
```

There doesn't appear to be any way to close the `<input>` tag or to move it outside the `<label>` tag.

When I don't add any CSS, it reads the CSS that DataTables automatically includes, which puts the "Search:" above the search box, not to its left. This web page hands whenever I try to paste that automatically generated CSS in this box, but here it is [in a Gist](https://gist.github.com/4281647).

Using CSS and the existing HTML, I'm now trying to make the word "Search:" appear to the left of the search box, with no luck.

Using SCSS, my latest attempt is:

```
.dataTables_filter label {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
  text-align: right;
  input {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Which compiles to:

```
.dataTables_filter label {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
  text-align: right;
}

.dataTables_filter label input {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

The automatically included CSS file is:

Comment: Are you asking visually have the label text to the left of the field? If so, that's the default way that HTML would render. Just over-ride whatever CSS is changing it.

Comment: An `id` can't contain white-space, and must be closed (you're missing a closing quote).

Comment: fixed the typo in the id above, thanks

Comment: it does what you want without any CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/mgQrt/

Comment: To clarify what I and Zoltan said, the issue is that you need to figure out what styles are over-riding the default behavior.

Comment: Is the class on the container `dataTables_filter` or is it two classes: `dataTables filter`? You have a mismatch between the markup and CSS selector.

Comment: DataTable has stopped working. Gotta get it up again, then I'll try disabling the automatically included stylsheet, and then manually copying across any styles from that sheet that I think I'll need. Working fast. Will get back to you all ASAP!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the search box was extending to the full width of the div, leaving no room for the label. Once I reduced its width, the label slotted into place.

Answer (score 0):

u can use ajax to reorder them

http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/